# React map function confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am a little confused with the map function when using it in a React Component. I have a Recipes Component that gets passed the recipes data from the App Component.

**APP COMPONENT**

```
<Recipes recipes={recipes} />
```

**RECIPES COMPONENT**

```
export default class Recipes extends Component {
  // THIS FUNCTION IS RETURNING NOTHING
  renderRecipes() {
    return this.props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
      <h1>{recipe.name}</h1>
    });
  }
  render() {
    let recipe = this.props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
      return (
        <h1>{recipe.name}</h1>
      );
    });
    return(
      <div>
        // CALLING THE FUNCTION HERE DOES NOT WORK
        { this.renderRecipes() }
        // HOWEVER CALLING THE VARIABLE DOES WORK
        { recipe }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where I am confused. Creating a function which does the `map` function returns nothing, however moving the `map` function and assigning the output to the `recipe` variable inside `render()` works fine. Why does the `map` function in `renderRecipes` return nothing?

Comment: not returning in map of `renderRecipes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything inside `map` body, use it like this:

```
renderRecipes() {
    return this.props.recipes.map((recipe, i) => {
        return <h1 key={i}> {recipe.name} </h1>
    });
}
```

or remove the `{}`:

```
renderRecipes() {
    return this.props.recipes.map((recipe, i) => <h1 key={i}> {recipe.name} </h1> );
}
```

> When `{}` is required with map?

When you want to do some calculation or want to return different elements on the basis of some condition then use `{}` to create a scope to define some variables and to use if conditions but here you just want to return a single element so `{}` is not required here.

**Note:** You need to assign unique `key` to each element, here i used index but i will suggest you to use any unique property of recipe object.

Comment: That did it! Will accept when I can. I am guessing I will need the `{}` if I want to return multiple lines of html? Thanks